# Template matching for colored image input

Tags: opencv, template-matching

I have a working code for template matching.  But it only works if the input image is converted into grayscale. Is it possible to do template matching considering the template color as well that needs to be found in the given image?

```
inputImg = cv2.imread("location")
template = cv2.imread("location")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it but why?

The idea of converting to the grey-scale is to apply the selected edge-detection algorithm to find the features of the input image.

Since you are working the features the possibility of finding the template image in the original image will be higher. As a result, converting to grey-scale has two advantages. Accuracy and computational complexity.

The `matchTemplate` method is also working for the RGB images. Now you need to find the image characteristic for 3 different channels. Yet you are not sure about whether your features robust or not, since most edge-detection algorithms are designed for the grey-scale images.